# Strange issue with a multi pass, multi RT render in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fbo

I am seeing a strange issue with a multi pass, multi RT ping-pong render

I am using 3 shaders and an FBO, I get no errors at any stage. I am using opengl 4, so I am not using glBegin/glEnd, I use my own matrices for transformation and i am using vertex buffers for rendering

The general idea of this test is to render 3 different colours to three separate fbo attachments (I realise that it is not efficient rendering the vbo twice in the first pass but this is just to help me understand a problem in some other source) I then bind a separate set of textures to the fbo and use the first set as the samplers. The final pass is to blend the results into the back buffer

What is odd is that the output is both quads appear red, when the first should be red and the second green (as these values come from the second shader).

If i change the function SamplePix in the second shader to always take from the second sampler both appear green, and if lookups up from the third then all appears yellow, but it seems to only read from one.

For now I can't seem to explain why I can read from each sampler ok but the loop doesn't seem to lookup correctly (in shader 2)

Also if I switch to rendering the texture sampled in shader 2 i see a black quad in the second pass (image 2)

Hopefully someone can throw some light on the problem. (I have also tried adding a sync fence object after the first pass but this didn't make a difference)

[image: red]

Texture Sample:

[image: tex]

```
// initial setup of shaders and vertex buffers ommitted for now (in separate source files)

// fbo setup like so
const int DepthLayers = 3;

bool InitFBO()
{
// width and height 768pixels
    for (int j=0; j<DepthLayers; j++)
    {
        const int idx = j + (DepthLayers*i);

        glGenTextures(1, &g_FBOManager.m_fboTex[ idx ]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.m_fboTex[ idx ]);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        //no mipmaps
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, g_XMLSettings->WWidth(), g_XMLSettings->WHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


        //depth
        glGenTextures(1, &g_FBOManager.m_fboDepthTex[ idx ]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.m_fboDepthTex[ idx ]);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        //no mipmaps
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE/* GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE*/);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);

        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, g_XMLSettings->WWidth(), g_XMLSettings->WHeight(), 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.m_fboDepthTex[idx]);
        pglFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.m_fboDepthTex[idx], 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.m_fboTex[idx]);
        // attach a texture to FBO color attachment point
        pglFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.m_fboTex[idx], 0);


        // check FBO status
        pglBindFramebufferEXT( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, g_FBOManager.FboId(i) );
        if(!CheckFramebufferStatus())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    BindFrameBuffer(-1);    // unbind fbo

    if (GLGETERROR("1", fileBuf, lineBuf)) ;    // check for glErrors

    return true;    // all ok
}


// code to init second set of textures before the render loop

    const int w = g_XMLSettings->WWidth();  //res: 768 square
    const int h = g_XMLSettings->WHeight();
    glGenTextures(bufCount, &ttex[0]);  
    for (int i=0; i<bufCount; ++i)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ttex[i]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    }

const int bufCount = 3;

void EnableTexture1()
{
    glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_BackTexture);
    glUniform1iARB(g_pPassAShader->m_clr_idx, 0);
}

void RenderLoop()
{

    GLenum buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_EXT };

    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);       
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glUseProgramObjectARB(g_pPassAShader->m_glContext);

    EnableTexture1();

    //... code omitted to set transform matrix and supply to shader


    if (!BindFrameBuffer(0))
        assert(0);

    const GLuint DTex = g_FBOManager.GetDepthTexture(0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, DTex);
    pglFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, DTex, 0);
    for (UINT i=0; i<bufCount; ++i)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.GetTexture(i));
        pglFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_FBOManager.GetTexture(i), 0);
        if (!CheckFramebufferStatus())
            assert(0);
    }
    glDrawBuffers(bufCount,buffers); 
    // this is very important! if we don't clear it won't get written to
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    EnableTexture1();

    RenderVertexCache(0);

    //... code omitted to set transform matrix and supply to shader

    // render the second quad to other FBO tex
    RenderVertexCache(0);

    DisableShader(0);
    BindFrameBuffer(-1);    // unbinds fbo

//pass 2
    if (!BindFrameBuffer(0))
        assert(0);

    // bind other set of textures to the fbo
    for (UINT i=0; i<bufCount; ++i)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,ttex[i]);
        pglFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ttex[i], 0);
        if (!CheckFramebufferStatus())
            assert(0);
    }
    glDrawBuffers(bufCount,buffers); 
    // this is very important! if we don't clear it won't get written to
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT  );
    // bind our set from prev pass to the samplers as input
    glUseProgramObjectARB(g_pPassBShader->m_glContext);

    for (UINT i=0; i<bufCount; ++i)
    {
        glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0+i);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,g_FBOManager.GetTexture(i));
        glUniform1iARB(g_pPassBShader->m_intex_idx[i], i);
    }


    VertexBufferManager2::RenderUsingOrthoEx(g_pPassBShader);   // renders a full screen quad

    DisableShader(0);
    BindFrameBuffer(-1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// pass 3
    glUseProgramObjectARB(g_pPassCShader->m_glContext);
    for (UINT i=0; i<bufCount; ++i)
    {
        glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0+i);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ttex[i]);
        glUniform1iARB(g_pPassCShader->m_intex_idx[i], i);
    }

    VertexBufferManager2::RenderUsingOrthoEx(g_pPassCShader);



    if (GLGETERROR("at1", fileBuf, lineBuf)) ;  // reports any glErrors

}

// the three shaders (fragment shaders only)
// vertex shaders transfer uv's and transform vertices (version set to 410 in all)

// shader for pass1
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 410

uniform sampler2D   g_ClrMap;
in vec2         g_InterpUV;     // supplied by vshader
out vec4        g_FBOLayers[ 3 ];

void main(void)
{   
    vec4 tex = texture(g_ClrMap, g_InterpUV);   // if we set fbo from texture only first texture renders
    g_FBOLayers[0] = vec4(1,0,0,.5);
    g_FBOLayers[1] = vec4(0,1,0,1);
    g_FBOLayers[2] = vec4(1,1,0,1);
}


// shader pass 2
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 410

uniform sampler2D   g_inLayers0;
uniform sampler2D   g_inLayers1;
uniform sampler2D   g_inLayers2;
in vec2         g_InterpUV ;
out vec4        g_FBOLayers[ 3 ];
vec2            fTextureSize;

vec4 SamplePix(in int buf, in vec2 tCoords, in float lod)
{
    if (buf==1)
        return textureLod(g_inLayers1, tCoords, lod);
    else if (buf==2)
        return textureLod(g_inLayers2, tCoords, lod);
    return textureLod(g_inLayers0, tCoords, lod);
}

void main(void)
{   
    ivec2 iCoords = ivec2(int(gl_FragCoord.x),int(gl_FragCoord.y));
    ivec2 iTextureSize = textureSize(g_inLayers0,0);
    fTextureSize = vec2(float(iTextureSize.x), float(iTextureSize.y));
    vec2 coords = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/iTextureSize.x,gl_FragCoord.y/iTextureSize.y);

    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        g_FBOLayers[i] = vec4(0.,0.,0.,0.); 
    }
    int j = 0;
    for(; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        g_FBOLayers[j] = SamplePix(j,coords,0); 

    }

}

// shader pass 3    
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 410

uniform sampler2D   g_inLayers0;
uniform sampler2D   g_inLayers1;
uniform sampler2D   g_inLayers2;
in vec2         g_InterpUV ;
out vec4        g_PixColour;

vec4 tFetch(in int buf, in ivec2 tCoords, in int lod)
{
    if (buf==1)
        return texelFetch(g_inLayers1, tCoords, lod);
    if (buf==2)
        return texelFetch(g_inLayers2, tCoords, lod);

    return texelFetch(g_inLayers0, tCoords, lod);
}

void main(void)
{   
    ivec2 iCoords = ivec2(int(gl_FragCoord.x),int(gl_FragCoord.y));
    ivec2 iTextureSize = textureSize(g_inLayers0,0);
    vec2 coords = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/iTextureSize.x,gl_FragCoord.y/iTextureSize.y);

    vec4 colour =  vec4(0.,0.,0.,0.);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i <2; ++i) // 3rd texture omitted for now
    {
        vec4 texel = tFetch(i,iCoords,0);
        if(texel.a + colour.a <= 1.0)
        {
            colour.rgb += (texel.rgb*texel.a);
            colour.a += texel.a;

        }
        else
        {
            texel.a -= (texel.a + colour.a) - 1.0;
            colour.rgb += (texel.rgb*texel.a);
            colour.a += texel.a;    
            break;      
        }

    }

    g_PixColour = colour;

}
```

Comment: I found that if you un-roll the loop in shader 2 it works (at least with textures)

Comment: This is an awful mess. Can't you just extract what we call a "minimal case" that can be used to reproduce the error? That would help not only people answering your question, but you may in fact discover what's the problem by doing that. Your shader seems to be ok but the code itself is using some library and the error might actually be caused by the third shader, not by the second. What if you reverse the order of textures (call SamplePix(2 - j, coords, 0) in the 2nd shader? Also, what is your hardware? The early programmable hardware used to have some issues with cycles and function calls.

Comment: I think your problem is  incorrect binding of the textures.I had this kind of issues too when first started with multi RT FBOs.And yes ,your code is complete mess as afore aforementioned.Clean it up and put some compact example if you can.